# Keras fit prints out matrices

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've got a rather strange error. I'm trying to use images as an input to a Keras model however when I run the fit function it just prints out a long list of matrices.

[image: matrices]

I've tried adding a log file callback but it doesn't output anything. The code shows the above output and fills the terminal window. There don't appear to be any errors.

So I tried removing bits of code to see where the problem is coming from. I literally removed all the layers to my network:

```py
model = Sequential()

# ... removed all layers! Still getting weird matrices printout

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy']#, 
              #validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
              #shuffle = True
              )

from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
csv_logger = CSVLogger('C:\\temp\\log.csv', append=True, separator=';')

model.fit(x=[X_train[:1]],
          y=[y_train[:1]],
          verbose=2,
          epochs=1, 
          callbacks=[csv_logger],
          batch_size=1)
```

I've tried to make this as quick and simple as possible reducing epocs to 1 etc..

The input is a list of normalized images.

Comment: Are you sure it is not some other code that is in your script?

Comment: The simplest (and dirtiest) way to know which command prints that numpy array is to put `print("some-string-to-identify")` around candidate lines. Did you try doing such printing before your `model = Sequential()` and after your `model.fit(...)`? Are you sure that printing is done in the section of code you are showing?

Comment: I managed to resolve this though I'm not quite sure what I did. I think it might have been a problem with data dimensionality.